# Having a problem with Flutter Doctor on Arch Linux

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-doctor

I am running Arch Linux.

I have a problem where `flutter doctor` doesn't recognize my Android Sdk.

My Flutter Doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Arch Linux 5.16.15-arch1-1, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Android Studio
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Here is a more detailed summary:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Arch Linux 5.16.15-arch1-1, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at /home/tt/Downloads/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (3 weeks ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /home/tt/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/211.7628.21.2111.8193401
    • Flutter plugin version 65.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 211.7808
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

As you can see, it doesn't recognize my Android Sdk.
I tried this:

`flutter config --android-sdk /home/tt/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-32/android.jar`

and I got:

```
Setting "android-sdk" value to "/home/tt/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-32/android.jar".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.
```

I ran `flutter doctor` but didn't work. I restarted my machine and it still doesn't work.

I already had Android Studio from the Toolbox Application. I tried installing it from the `.tar.gz` version. Still doesn't work. I installed from the AUR, but nothing works.

Can you please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set ANDROID_HOME in your environment variable.

On ~/.bashrc of you are using bash or ~/.zshrc if you are using zsh in the last line put

```
export ANDROID_HOME=[SDK-PATH]
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: still doesn't work, any other solution?

Comment: What are you getting from echo $ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: You can also manually edit your path in flutter config  by running "flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk"

Comment: I did so. And is /home/[USER]/Android/Sdk/platofroms/android-32/android.jar a valid android sdk path, because i don't know what the android sdk refers to, i just know that the directory is ~/Android/Sdk

Comment: Provide path only to SDK folder, not jar file. In your case path will be /home/[USER]/Android/Sdk/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the PATH of Android SDK Command-Line Tools and Android SDK Build Tools.

Put the following lines at the end of the ~/.bachrc file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/XXX/Android/Sdk/"
export PATH="$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}cmdline-tools/latest/bin/:${ANDROID_HOME}build-tools/33.0.0/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"
```

Note that **XXX**, **latest**, and **33.0.0** must be changed according to your installation.